# DocumentRoot does not exist while creating container using docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, apache, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro OS (Arch based) and trying to create a container for laravel project with below Dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.1.8-apache

MAINTAINER Nayan Verma

COPY . /srv/http
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /srv/http \
    && a2enmod rewrite 

RUN service apache2 restart
```

To initialize the container I have run the command : (where Dockerfile and vhost.conf are inside the .docker folder)

```
sudo docker build --file .docker/Dockerfile -t privatechat .
```

Container get build up giving an error that DocumentRoot not found in vhost.conf file. vhost.conf file is as follows :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/privatechat.com/public/"

    <Directory "/srv/http/privatechat.com/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I have checked multiple times and seems like path is correct to me even though I'm getting this error :

```
Restarting web server: apache2AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/srv/http/privatechat.com/public/] does not exist
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Any help will be really appreciable.

[image: Below is the file dir structure]

Comment: Comment out the line `DocumentRoot "/srv/http/privatechat.com/public/"` in `vhost.conf` file to let the image build and then `exec` into it to see if your files are correctly copied. Or change the path to something like `/root/`

Comment: Thanks @Saeed I have tried by commenting out the DocumentRoot but still getting the same error. Well I'm not sure about changing the path. Can you please let me know a bit more about it?

Comment: Just instead of `/srv/http/privatechat.com/public/` in `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` directives, write `DocumentRoot /root/` and `Directory /root/`